# Tomcat 7 Access Log with Client Certificate Subject Name

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, logging, client-certificates

I am trying to include client certificate information in my tomcat access log file.

I've reviewed this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/624790/tomcat-log-the-equivalent-of-ssl-client-s-dn but this only returns a reference to the cert and I can't actually extract any properties.

My logfile pattern looks like this:

```
pattern="... [%{javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate}r]"
```

This is returning: [[Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate;@667a078]

Is there a way to access the certificate properties such as this:

```
pattern="... [%{javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate.SubjectName}r]"
```

I'd like to be able to extract certificate information without any code modification.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this without any code modification?

Comment: Sadly no. Ended up terminating client certificates elsewhere and dumping to splunk.

Answer (score 0):

If you authenticate the user using that subject name, then I think you can log the user name with "`%u`"

If you need anything else, you need to write a `javax.servlet.Filter` or a `ServletRequestListener` that sets that value as an attribute on `ServletRequest`. The value can be any object that implements toString().

The `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` request attribute is an array of certificates and is defined in the Servlet Specification ch.3.9 SSL Attributes (Servlet Spec 3.1)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. The only way I figured out is to Override AccessLogValve.

1. Create a simple maven java project
2. `<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
     <version>x.x.x</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>`
3. Override AccessLogValve and implement
     `@Override
     public void log(Request request, Response response, long time) {`
4. Read your principal from the X509Certificate from the request (unfortunately i cannot share this code)
   `request.setUserPrincipal(xyz)`
5. pack the jar
6. copy it to your tomcat lib folder
7. confix server.xml to use your Valve, replace Valve class with yours

   `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"-->`